# How to benchmark react native app with the latest react-native version (0.47)

Tags: react-native

Perf has been removed , and I could not find a right way to benchmark my app and know the performance , systrace is not very useful for JS side .

So Is there a proper way to benchmark with latest react native app ?

Comment: Not equivalent to having systrace etc. but [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15371) mentions using 'ReactPerf' and [react-native-console-time-polyfill](https://github.com/MaxGraey/react-native-console-time-polyfill) to get some performance insights.